# package unavilable shared library failing android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-library

Hi I am trying to use a external project i got from github(AccordionWidgetDemoActivity) as library in my application. I made the project as library in eclipse adt and addeed the same library in my application. I have also added the application in the project buildpath. however I am getting the following errror when i try to launch the application

> *[2014-03-15 05:19:35 - Sample] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY [2014-03-15 05:19:35 - Sample]
>   Please check logcat output for more details. [2014-03-15 05:19:35 -
>   Sample] Launch canceled!*

In Log cat I am getting the following errro 
**

*> Package com.example.sample requires unavailable shared library

> com.sentaca.android.accordion; failing!*

**

I have added the library in android manifest as follows as package name in src folder in the library project

i have googled around and everythhing refers to google maps. I am a beginner in android and Request help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are including the library as part of the project, to do this go to `properties->Android` at the bottom you should see the library reference, if it is not there just click on `add` and select the library.

Also, go to `properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export` and check the library otherwise the it won't be uploaded to the device-emulator.

Hope this helps.